# How to unit test quartz in camel

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, apache-camel

I am having problem in figuring out how to test my route which use `quartz` in its `from`
My `spring` file

```
<spring:route id="metricExtractionTimer" startupOrder="1">
    <spring:from uri="quartz://metricExtractionTimer?fireNow=true"/>
    <transform>
        <simple>........... Object Added to DB ...........</simple>
    </transform>
    <to uri="stream:out"/>
    <to uri="mock:result"/>
</spring:route>
```

My Test File

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@BootstrapWith(CamelTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/beans-test.xml")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class MetricExtractionTest{

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Produce(uri = "quartz://metricExtractionTimer?fireNow=true")
    protected ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testQuartzCron() throws Exception {
        producerTemplate.sendBody(null);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route metricExtractionTimer because of startupOrder clash. Route quartz already has startupOrder 1 configured which this route have as well. Please correct startupOrder to be unique among all your routes.
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doCheckStartupOrderClash(DefaultCamelContext.java:3414)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3364)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3147)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3003)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:172)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2799)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2795)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2818)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2795)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2764)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestContextLoader$7.execute(CamelSpringTestContextLoader.java:515)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestHelper.doToSpringCamelContexts(CamelSpringTestHelper.java:92)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestContextLoader.handleCamelContextStartup(CamelSpringTestContextLoader.java:509)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestContextLoader.loadContext(CamelSpringTestContextLoader.java:164)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestContextLoader.loadContext(CamelSpringTestContextLoader.java:87)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Camel makes trouble manually triggering a self-triggering route, which is kind of understandable. Also, you don't really want to test the Camel Quartz module, since this already well tested open-source code.

I suggest you make the quartz route call a sub-route with a [direct:yourRouteName consumer](https://camel.apache.org/direct.html). That one can then be called smoothly from your unit test.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, you don't really want to test the Camel Quartz module, since this already well tested open-source code.

Don't agree with this statement. By that reasoning we shouldn't test our interactions with other frameworks as well, e.g. Spring, Hibernate, Camel, etc.

@Bilal: Your best bet is to look at how the camel-quartz2 project tests itself [1].

Specifically, you can look at [2] and [3].

[1] https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-quartz2/src/test

[2] https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-quartz2/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/quartz2/SpringQuartzCronRouteTest.java

[3] https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-quartz2/src/test/resources/org/apache/camel/component/quartz2/SpringQuartzCronRouteTest.xml

As an example:

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0/2+*+*+*+*+?")
        .to("mock:result");
  }
}


@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyRouteTest {

  @Autowired
  private CamelContext camelContext;

  @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
  private MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

  @Test
  public void testRoute() throws Exception {
    resultEndpoint.expectedMinimumMessageCount(3);

    MockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied(camelContext);
  }
}
```